# Loop through generator two items at a time

Tags: python, generator

I have defined a generator that yields log entries from Elasticsearch:

```
def gen():
    ....
    for hit in results:
        yield hit
```

How can I loop through two elements at the same time? Something in the lines of:

```
for one, two in gen():
    ...
```

By two elements I mean this: `A, B`, `B, C`, ..., `Y, Z` (for a generated list of `A, B, ..., Y, Z`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answering your updated question, use `itertools.tee` to construct a second iterator, advance the second iterator once and discard the result, then loop over both iterators in pairs using `zip`.

```
>>> from itertools import tee
>>> it = iter('abc')
>>> it1, it2 = tee(it)
>>> 
>>> next(it2, None)
'a'
>>> for first, second in zip(it1, it2):
...     first, second
... 
('a', 'b')
('b', 'c')
```

> Thank you. This is the cleanest, most "pythonic" way to do it? I feel the solution to this simple problem is to complex.

I don't think there is a cleaner solution. In fact, it's the `pairwise` recipe from the [itertools docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html):

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the cleanest, most "pythonic" way to do it? I feel the solution to this simple problem is to complex.

Comment: @AndreiHorak no problem, make sure to use `izip` like in the recipe if you are using Python 2, especially if your iterators/generators could yield an infinite amount of objects.

Comment: Using `tee` is good if you only have an iterator, but probably if you know you are working with a `list` or other container directly you can just use two-calls to `iter` like so: `it1, it2 = iter(my_list), iter(my_list)`

Comment: Although, I missed that these were log entries from Elasticsearch, so `tee` is the way to go!

Answer (score 10):

This answer assumes you want non-overlapping pairs. You can do this via `zip()` because the iterator is consumed:

```
for one, two in zip(gen, gen):
    # do something
```

Example:

```
>>> gen = (x for x in range(5))
>>> for one, two in zip(gen, gen): print(one,two)
... 
0 1
2 3
```

Note, as [timgeb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3620003/timgeb) commented, you should use `itertools.zip_longest` if you have an uneven number of elements and you want the last one with a fill value, for example:

```
>>> gen = (x for x in range(5))
>>> for one, two in zip_longest(gen, gen): print(one, two)
... 
0 1
2 3
4 None
```

Comment: Will this ensure the same order for the elements and also reusing of the previously loaded item?

Comment: Note that this will not yield the last element if there's an uneven amount of objects to be yielded from the generator. In that case, using `itertools.izip_longest` will get you `(last_element, None)` (or any fill-value you desire).

Comment: @AndreiHorak what do you mean, "reusing of the previously loaded item"?

Comment: @timgeb thanks yep, i went with `zip_longest` (assuming Python 3)

Comment: @AndreiHorak I see, with your update clarifying, use timgeb's answer just posted (was thinking of a similar thing to update myself)

Answer (score 0):

I once solved the similar problem with following :

```
def gen():
    results = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    for i, v in enumerate(results):
        # if i < len()
        if (i + 1) < len(results):
            yield (v, results[i + 1])
        else:
            yield v


output = gen()

for each in output:
    print(each)
```

Output will be:

```
(1, 2)
(2, 3)
(3, 4)
(4, 5)
5
```

Comment: Since the generator loops through paged Elasticsearch results, I don't think it's that optimal to load everything into memory there in order to group items two by two.